# Can I use a Linux boot stick to check a windows system?

Tags: linux, boot, storage, ext2

I have tried casper-rw and ext2.

The following questions are where I'm at:

1. Can I use a Linux boot stick to check the desktop windows partition for viruses and/or rootkits? If not, why?
2. How is a casper-rw file different from a casper-rw partition (or is it the same thing?)
3. What are limitations of a persistence Linux boot stick that I might (and most probably are) not be aware of?

Comment: You can definitely solve windows problems by booting up a live distribution, but you might need some special programs, Kali is a goto for windows related problems. Casper-rw partition is definitely better. Its mostly the speed that is a problem with usb live sticks.

Comment: kali? Don't think the kali distro is a good place to start for the linux novice... Linux boot will allow you to do most anything needed on your Windows partitions.

Comment: For item 1: Yes, you can. What specifically do you need to do? Item 2: Same thing, a casper-rw file is treated as if it is a writable partition. For item 3: Did you mean _persistence_ when you referred to 'permanent storage'? See https://www.pendrivelinux.com/what-is-persistent-linux/ . Please click [edit] and advise if you wanted to discuss _persistance_.  And, suggest you see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me before seizing on Kali as a possible solution.

Comment: @jc__  I agree with Kali Linux not being the best option to get to know the Linux universe. Then again I usually drive on curiosity as a motivator - so sometimes I don't go the obvious/convenient way. I'll keep it in mind though.

Comment: @K7AAY 1. Mostly virus /rootkit scans or data rescue 2. understood 3. That's what I meant - thanks for clarifying. Will check out the links you provided >>

Comment: @K7AAY enhanced the first question accordingly - thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @GAD3R thanks! I guess it's not hard to see I'm new to this. Is it "acceptable" if I just edit it down to one question in this case? Obviously I don't want to cross any rules.

Comment: Absolutely OK to revise the question to just one issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: *Can I use a Linux boot stick to check the desktop windows partition for viruses and/or rootkits?* Yes, you can.  Examples include [Bitdefender](https://www.fosslinux.com/1098/create-a-bootable-bitdefender-antivirus-rescue-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-and-linux-mint.htm/), [AntiVirus Live](http://antiviruslivecd.4mlinux.com/), and [numerous](https://www.techsupportall.com/best-bootable-antivirus-rescue-severely-infected-computer/) [others](https://www.lifewire.com/free-bootable-antivirus-tools-2625785).

2: *How is a casper-rw file different from a casper-rw partition?* Same thing, a casper-rw file is treated as if it is a writable partition, and is used to store your changes and additions to the filesystem.

3: *What are limitations of a Linux boot stick with persistence that I might (and most probably are) not be aware of?* They boot slower, and most LiveUSB creation tools ([one example](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/casper-rw-creator-make-a-persistent-file-from-windows/)), if they offer persistence, are limited to a maximum of 4095 KB in persistent size. See https://www.pendrivelinux.com/what-is-persistent-linux for an overview and, for an explanation of how to exceed that normal limit, see https://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition .